# How to show a div when mouse approaches the top of the page

Tags: jquery, css, html, mouseover

I'm trying to obtain a menu with an auto-hide (or better auto show) effect, mimicking the way the osx bar hides and unhides itself as soon as the mouse gets near to the bottom of the screen.

In my case the menu is on the top. It's a div, positioned out the the screen (top:-270px) and enter the screen once you've scrolled down the page for 200px. This is the jquery code (the $j is for compatibility with other scripts):

```
$j(function( $ ){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var yPos = ( $(window).scrollTop() );
        if(yPos > 200) { // show sticky menu after screen has scrolled down 200px from the top      
                        $('header').css("top","0").fadeIn();
        } else {
                        $('header').css("top","-270px");
        }
    });
});
```

It works perfectly. But I would like show the menu even when the mouse get near the top of the screen (and obviously I still haven't scroll down).

Any help?

Comment: Here is a good JSFIDDLE Example - http://jsfiddle.net/moojjoo/tneb97wk/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an (updated) approach that uses a containing div has a hover target (I've added more colors to make it easier to see the effect) ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PaZHH/1/))

```
<div id='HoverSpace'>
  <div id='HiddenMenu'>
    <a href="#">Option 1</a>
    <a href="#">Option 2</a>
    <a href="#">Option 3</a>
    <a href="#">Option 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  var hoverMenu = $('#HiddenMenu');

  $('#HoverSpace').on('mousemove', function (event) {
    if (35 - event.clientY < 0) {
        hoverMenu.css({
            top: 35 - event.clientY
        });
    } else {
        hoverMenu.css({
            top: 0
        });
    }
  }).on('mouseout', function () {
    hoverMenu.css({
        top: -35
    });
  });
</script>
<style>
  #HiddenMenu {
    background-color: #e00;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
  }
  #HoverSpace {
    background-color: #aeaeae;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 45px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: dont use .hover I would use .mouseover or .mouseenter

Comment: [.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is short hand for `$(selector).mouseenter(handlerIn).mouseleave(handlerOut);`

Comment: @Cam, I've extended the code to have the revel start as you approach the menu and then snap into place once you are close enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do this (not tested and probably you will need to review the hiding logic):

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  var vertical = e.pageY;

  if(vertical <= 2 && !$('header').is(":visible")) {      
    $('header').css("top","0").fadeIn();
  } else {
    $('header').css("top","-270px");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [.mousemove](http://api.jquery.com/mousemove/), mousemove can track your mouse movements and you can actually detect the mouse moving across the screen. When it moves up towards the top you can say at some point in Y axis to start showing, or hiding.